# Starting standalone webdriver server for IE using gulp and protractor E2E

Tags: selenium, gulp, protractor, gulp-protractor

I tried to find this everywhere but couldn't find any solution for this.

I am using Gulp with protractor to start my perform my E2E testing. Below is the code i am using in Gulp.

```
gulp.task('serve', function(cb) {
 runModule('webdriver-manager', ['start'], cb);
});
gulp.task('update', function(cb) {
runModule('./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager', ['update'], cb);
});
function runModule(name, params, cb) {
  new simpleCommand(path.join(binPath, name), params, process.cwd()).run(cb);
}
```

Now i want to start a standalone webdriver for IE using `webdriver-manager start --standalone` but I am not sure how to do it. If i use  below code, it is not working and still it is asking me to start standalone webdriver for IE.

```
gulp.task('serve', function(cb) {
     runModule('webdriver-manager', ['start','--standalone], cb);
    });
```

Strange thing is if i comment out my webdriver start and update task above still my chrome tasks are running fine. I am not sure how to make it run from IE.
Below is what i have in my protractor.conf file.

```
multiCapabilities = [{
      browserName: 'internet explorer',
        maxInstances  : 2,
    }];
```

Can someone please help me with this?